# How to make top of page visible in iphone simulator when running selenium tests

Tags: iphone, selenium, safari, simulator

When I run Selenium tests (using the Selenium iWebDriver xcode project) against a web app (built on jQuery Mobile) on the iPhone simulator, the top of the page is always cut off (1st image).  When I load the app normally in Safari (2nd image), everything looks fine.  Is there a way to make the Selenium case always show the top of the page.  I've tried window.scrollTo(0,1), but that didn't make a difference.  In fact, when I drag to scroll up, I see the top of the page, but as soon as I release the top of the page bounces back to its former hidden position (1st image).

**Loaded in simulator using Selenium iWebDriver:**

[image: loaded using selenium]

**Loaded normally in Safari:**

[image: loaded normally]

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The UIWebView in the Selenium iWebDriver xcode [project](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn) is sized specifically for the Simulator when the Simulator's device setting is 'iPhone retina 4-inch'.

So I created a new project based off the original Selenium 'iphone' xcode project and modified the UIWebView's dimensions to fit the Simulator when the Simulator's device setting is 'iPhone' or 'iPhone retina 3.5-inch'.

It's too bad that I need a separate project for each type of display.  Maybe there's a better way (programmatic) to fix this, but I'm not familiar enough with iOS development to know what that might be.